# Forwarding the containers stdout logs to datadog without datadog agents

Tags: docker, kubernetes, datadog

We re trying to eliminate Datadog agents from our infrastructure. I am trying to find a solution to forward the containers standard output logs to be visualised on datadog but without the agents and without changing the dockerfiles because there are hundreds of them.

I was thinking about trying to centralize the logs with rsyslog but I dont know if its a good idea. Any suggestions ?

Comment: curious: why do you want to eliminate Datadog agents from your infrastructure? For container log collection, there are some advantages to using the Datadog agent. What I have in mind: it's really easy to get all the container metadata added to your logs, like labels etc.

Comment: Because we re not using datadog anymore for the infrastructure metrics monitoring we migrated to grafana /prometheus and the agents are for the logs and the metrics. and we pay for it. so we re trying to find another solution for the logs

Comment: If you like, you can still just use the datadog agent, but only for logs. Especially if you already have log collection enabled and working, this may be a low-work option for you. There are other options though if this still isn't what you want -- i'm interested to hear your thoughts. https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/faq/the-datadog-agent-for-logs-or-traces-only/?tab=logs

Comment: what are the the other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This doc will show you a comprehensive list](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/#cat-log-collection) of all integrations that involve log collection. Some of these include other common log shippers, which can also be used to forward logs to Datadog. Among these you'd find...

- [Fluentd](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/fluentd/#log-collection)
- [Logstash](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/logstash/#log-collection)
- [Rsyslog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/rsyslog/?tab=datadogussite) (for linux)
- [Syslog-ng](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/syslog_ng/?tab=datadogussite) (for linux, windows)
- [nxlog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/nxlog/?tab=datadogussite) (for windows)

That said, you [can still just use the Datadog agent to collect logs only](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/faq/the-datadog-agent-for-logs-or-traces-only/?tab=logs) (they want you to collect everything with their agent, that's why they warn you against collecting just their logs).

If you want to collect logs from docker containers, the Datadog agent is an easy way to do that, and it has the benefit of adding lots of relevant docker-metadata as tags to your logs. ([Docker log collection instructions here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/docker/?tab=containerinstallation).)

If you don't want to do that, I'd look at Fluentd first on the list above -- it has a good reputation for containerized log collection, promotes JSON log formatting (for easier processing), and scales reasonably well.